# Torchtext import error on macbook air m1. Used pip3 to install all of it

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, torchtext

While the installation went smooth, I keep facing this error when I try to import torchtext on my macbook air m1

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import torchtext

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/__init__.py:6, in <module>
      3 from torch.hub import _get_torch_home
      5 # the following import has to happen first in order to load the torchtext C++ library
----> 6 from torchtext import _extension  # noqa: F401
      8 _TEXT_BUCKET = "https://download.pytorch.org/models/text/"
     10 _CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(_get_torch_home(), "text"))

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:64, in <module>
     59     # This import is for initializing the methods registered via PyBind11
     60     # This has to happen after the base library is loaded
     61     from torchtext import _torchtext  # noqa
---> 64 _init_extension()

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:58, in _init_extension()
     55 if not _mod_utils.is_module_available("torchtext._torchtext"):
     56     raise ImportError("torchtext C++ Extension is not found.")
---> 58 _load_lib("libtorchtext")
     59 # This import is for initializing the methods registered via PyBind11
     60 # This has to happen after the base library is loaded
     61 from torchtext import _torchtext

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:50, in _load_lib(lib)
     48 if not path.exists():
     49     return False
---> 50 torch.ops.load_library(path)
     51 return True

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/_ops.py:220, in _Ops.load_library(self, path)
    215 path = torch._utils_internal.resolve_library_path(path)
    216 with dl_open_guard():
    217     # Import the shared library into the process, thus running its
    218     # static (global) initialization code in order to register custom
    219     # operators with the JIT.
--> 220     ctypes.CDLL(path)
    221 self.loaded_libraries.add(path)

File /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py:365, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    362 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    364 if handle is None:
--> 365     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366 else:
    367     self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Users/pratik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/lib/libtorchtext.so, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3c1012OptionalType3getENS_4Type24SingletonOrSharedTypePtrIS1_EE
  Referenced from: /Users/pratik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torchtext/lib/libtorchtext.so
  Expected in: /Users/pratik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
```

I don't quite understand what I can do about this. I uninstalled and reinstalled it all to avoid an error I was having previously. But now, this comes up.